# List<T>.Remove(T item) removing item from original List

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I have the following code

```
foreach (var d in dots)
{
    var _tempPointList = new List<Point>();
    _tempPointList = _pointList;

    foreach (var point in _tempPointList)
    {
        if (d >= point.X && d <= point.Y)
        {
            _tempPointList.Remove(point);
        }
    }
}
```

so when the integer `d` is between `X` and `Y` of the point type, it will be removed from the temporary list because the next `d` doesn't have to check the same `_tempPointList` element. But when the code reaches `_tempPointList.Remove(point);` the point element is getting removed from the `_tempPointList` and `_pointList` which I felt strange. Why is it removing from the main list as well?

Comment: because both instances are referring to same memory location

Comment: Use .RemoveAll() with a predicate instead, you will spare a lot of lines of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are working on the same list. You are assigning effectively the same instance to `_tempPointList` in this line (and removing the reference to your original `_tempPointList` which you created in the line above.):

```
_tempPointList = _pointList;
```

I'd suggest you instantiate your copy list by directly copying the list with this call:

```
var _tempPointList = new List<Point>(_pointList); //creates a shallow copy
```

I see yet another problem: you are removing elements from a list while you are iterating over it. Don't you get an `System.InvalidOperationException` when continuing to iterate?

I'd solve this by iterating over the original list and remove from the copy list like this:

```
foreach (var d in dots)
{
    var _tempPointList = new List<Point>(_pointList);

    foreach (var point in _pointList)
    {
        if (d >= point.X && d <= point.Y)
        {
            _tempPointList.Remove(point);
        }
    }

    _pointList = _tempPointList;

}
```

As mentionend in the comments of your question, you could just use a predicate on [List.RemoveAll()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which deletes an item if the [predicate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns true. I didn't test the performance, but feel free to compare.

```
foreach (var d in dots)
{
    _pointList.RemoveAll(point => d >= point.X && d <= point.Y);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to make a copy of the list for your logic to work.

```
// instead of this
var _tempPointList = new List<Point>();

// make a copy like this
var _tempPointList = new List<Point>(_pointList);
```

Otherwise, you have just copied a reference to the list and both `_tempPointList` and `_pointList` point to same memory

Answer (score 2):

You're having this problem because both _tempPointList and _pointList have the same reference so when you modify one list the other is modified automatically. another problem you're having is with Foreach you can't moidify a list when iterating over it using Foreach